# Using flatmap for search function

Tags: swift, uisearchbar, flatmap

I have an array which loads into a TableView.

```
var sections = [

        Section(sec: "One",
                subSec: ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"],
                expanded: false),

        Section(sec: "Two",
                subSec: ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"],
                expanded: false),

        Section(sec: "Three",
                subSec: ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"],
                expanded: false),
```

Here is the definition for the sections:

```
struct Section {
    var sec: String!
    var subSec: [String]! // [ ] = Array of Strings
    var expanded: Bool!

    init(sec: String, subSec: [String], expanded: Bool) {
        self.sec = sec
        self.subSec = subSec
        self.expanded = expanded
    }
}
```

I am trying to build a search function. It works for a standard array but not my variable as it is more complex.
I have (with help) adjusted the code using flatmap but I don't know how to map it to the subSec strings.

```
func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
        filtered = sections.flatMap{ return $0.subSec.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) ? $0.subSec : nil }

        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

The error I am getting currently is: `Value type [String] has no value lowercased`

Additional Code:

```
var filtered = [Section]()
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
```

Comment: Do you want to search for sections that has sub sections with exactly the search text? Or does it just have to contain the search text?

Comment: Contain. i.e if I search for 'A' it will return all subSec that match A in the TableView

Comment: If you search for A, does it match ABC? Also, do you want the whole subsection array as a result, or just the string `"A"`?

Comment: Just the String "A". Example: If "A" is searched, then it would have a table view with three "A" fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Check if a string contains another string ignoring case

```
baseText.range(
    of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil
) != nil
```

### Code

If you want to get the whole section, then you don't need use `flatMap`, just use a `filter`

```
var filtered: [Section] = []

func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
    filtered = sections.filter { section in
        section.subSec.contains { 
            $0.range(
                of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil
            ) != nil 
        }
    }
}
```

---

But if in the section you want only those subsections that contain the searched text then

```
var filtered: [Section] = []

func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
    filtered = sections.map { section in
        var section = section
        section.subSec = section.subSec.filter {
            $0.range(
                of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil
            ) != nil
        }
        return section
    }
}
```

---

But if you want only subsections then

```
var filtered: [String] = []

func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
    filtered = sections.flatMap { section in
        section.subSec.filter {
            $0.range(
                of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil
            ) != nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the OP uses `flatMap` because he wanted `[String]` as result, instead of `[Section].`

Comment: Yes. I need to return a string to populate the filtered results in a table view

Answer (score 0):

Your error can be solved by `map`ping all the subsections to lowercase.

However, this will get you a `[[String]]` instead of `[String]` and the results are not what you wanted.

Let's describe what you want to do in words:

> flatten the `sections` so that I get a 1D array of all the subsections as strings
>
> only keep those elements in the subsections that match the search string.

To do the first thing, you need `flatMap`. To do the second, you need `filter`.

You can't use a single flat map for this because you can't return nil in the flat map closure to say "get rid of this".

```
let filtered: [String] = 
    sections.flatMap { $0.subSec }
             .filter { $0.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) }
```

Comment: Thanks. So do I use this in place of `filtered = sections.flatMap{ return $0.subSec.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) ? $0.subSec : nil }`

Comment: @128K Yes. `filtered` in your code should be a `[String]` right?

Comment: @Sweeper In question - Additional Code: `var filtered = [Section]()`, but in a comment to my answer, he said `[String]`

Comment: @128K Why is `filtered` a `[Section]`? It makes no sense. It should be `[String]`, shouldn't it?

Comment: I have changed it to String, you are correct. Thanks

Comment: Does the let filtered replace my filtered = sections.flapMap?

Comment: @128K No, you need to assign the result to your `filtered` property, _not_ a new constant created by `let`.

Comment: OK. I don't think I've understood correctly.  See edit

Comment: @128K sorry if I didn't explained well enough. Basically, remove `let` and `: [String]` from my code.

Comment: Thank you for all your help so far! That has fixed the error but it has now produced a Fatal Error: fatal error: _unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value_. This is on the following line: 
`tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar`

Comment: @128K I think that is out of the scope of this question. I suggest you to check whether `tableView` or `searchController.searchBar` is nil. I think the problem here is that you put this line at a place where one or more of the aforementioned variables have not been initialised. If you are still stuck, post another question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$0.subSec.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
```

you could try

```
$0.subSec.contains({$0.lowercased() == searchText.lowercased()})
```